# Cloud Function Increment counter without reading document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to increment or decrements a number in cloud functions without reading the document.

I have a item documents, and when the document updates, it check for quantity. if the quantity is more than zero, increment the store profile item count. So say the store has 10 items available, and item doc field has been updated from 0 to 1 inventory, i will need to increment the store item count to 11.

I remember reading on firebase blog that there is a new feature that allows this. But how do we do it in cloud functions ?

Answer (score 27):

You use the feature in Cloud Functions through the Admin SDK. Here is an example based on a project I'm working on.

First you import the Admin SDK:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

And then in your Cloud Function you increment the field with something like:

```
var firestore = admin.firestore();
var docRef = firestore.collection('your_collection').doc('your_document');
docRef.update({ itemCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) })
```

This increments the field `itemCount` by `1`.

Also see:

- the blog post [Incrementing Values Atomically with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html)
- the documentation on how to [Add the Admin SDK to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk)
- the reference documentation for [`admin.firestore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore)

Comment: const admin = require('firebase-admin');

docRef.update({
                   'availableItemsCount'  : admin.firestore().FieldValue.increment(1),
                });     

error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined
    at exports.setAvailableItemsCount.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:206:74)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: Hmmm.... I thought this feature had also been released in the Admin SDK. Let me check...

Comment: It's definitely available in `firebase-admin` `7.2.0` - @Mozesong you may need to update your dependencies.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `admin.firestore.FieldValue` and not `admin.firestore().FieldValue`?

Comment: Thanks oodavid, I somehow couldn't fid it. And thanks Renaud. I've been using this in a web app, so may have gotten the Admin SDK syntax wrong. But `FieldValue` is a "static" class, so should require getting the Firestore instance.

Comment: @Mozesong: as Renaud pointed out, it should be `admin.firestore.FieldValue` without parentheses after `firestore`.

Comment: it didnt work. docRef.update({
                    'availableItemsCount'  :  admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                 }); error: TypeError: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function
    at exports.setAvailableItemsCount.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:201:74)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7) version: firebase-admin@7.2.0

Comment: I just tested this on my own system, and after upgrading to version 7.2 of the Admin SDK `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` resolves there without a problem. I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: My firestore.d.ts does not have the increment() function. what do i do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am still unable to increment

Comment: Sorry @Mozesong, since I can't reproduce the problem there is not a lot I can do to help. You might want to see if you can include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. I understand that may be tricky, but at this point we're stuck at a "works on one machine, not on another", which makes it hard for me to help.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/597#issuecomment-482528306 solved. Partially my issue and also partially an update glitch.

Comment: Does the documentation need updating?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldValue

Comment: Yup, that seems to not be up to date. I just filed a bug for. Thanks for flagging!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but since cloud functions might run more than once in a single invocation, it is never safe to use FieldValue.increment in Cloud Functions, is it?

Comment: Note: The update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using TypeScript with the latest versions of `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin`, you should do this instead:

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
```